# Extension of action in algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I was asking [this on stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571989/extension-of-action-in-algebraic-groups) but I didn't get the answer.
Borel's book *Linear Algebraic Groups* contains the following result

> **10.9 Theorem.** Let $G$ be a connected affine group of dimension one. Then $G$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{G}_a$ or $\mathbb{G}_1$.

> **Proof**: $G$ is a dense open set in a unique complete smooth curve $\overline{G}$ (see AG.18.5(d)). It follows from (AG.18.5(f)) that **the action of $G$ on itself by translation extends uniquely to an action of $G$ on $\overline{G}$**...

Is the above extension of the action of $G$ as an action of abstract groups or also as algebraic groups.
Why?

Comment: The action of $G$ on itself by translation is a morphism $L_g:G\rightarrow G$ (which is only a homomorphism when $g=e$ is the neutral element of $G$) and the claim that is used by Borel is that the action $L_g$ extends to the complete curve $\overline{G}$ as a morphism $L_g:\overline{G}\rightarrow G$, which again is almost never a homomorphism.

Comment: Crossposted at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571989/extension-of-action-in-algebraic-groups

Comment: @FZaldivar thank you for your response

Comment: The map $g\mapsto L_g$ is a homomorphism.